# How to create a program that reads the last commands exit status?

Tags: c, linux, shell, exit-code

In Linux C, how do you read the last programs exit status.

For example:

```
true; echo $?
```

Will show a 0 for success. But I'd like to replace that with a C program:

```
true; ./echo_exit_status
```

How/where is the last exit code $? available to a C program?

Comment: I don't think you can (without otherwise supplying it to the C program).

Comment: That information is stored in the shell process. There's no way a C program (even if it's a subprocess of the shell) can access it.

Comment: I thought that said Ken Thompson

Comment: @true: I read so all the time.

Comment: One possible solution is read the `$?` variable value from your C program.

Comment: @Jack How would you suggest to do that ? By hacking in the shell's own memory ?

Comment: @Jack, only variables exported by the shell into the environment can be read from subprocesses. `$?` is not.

Comment: @zakinster: I don't know, that's why I said "possible".  I throught it were a variable just like, say, `PATH`.

Comment: you could patch the shell to `setenv("?",lastexitvalue,1)` and _then_ you could use getenv("?"); busybox hush for instance, you'd need to `setenv("?",utoa(G.last_exitcode),1)` anytime G.last_exitcode is changed.

Comment: @Jack, `PATH` is an *environment variable* (available to all programs), not a *shell variable* (available only to the shell); by contrast, `$?` is not just a regular shell variable (which you could expose to the environment, and thus to subprocesses, using `export`) but a special parameter with its own expansion behavior, and which can't be exported at all.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? For most use cases, the Right Thing is to wrap the program whose exit status you care about -- that way it runs as your child, so you can `wait()` for it yourself. (As a wrapper, instead of `true; ./echo_exit_status`, your users would run `./echo_exit_status true`).

Answer (score 2):

The last command's exit status is **not** accessible to a subsequently-executed program (absent insanely-horrible hackery -- attaching to the parent shell with a debugger or somesuch).

You could write a shell function or helper that exported this value into the environment -- but no solution is possible which does not require the shell's involvement.

Answer (score -2):

You'd have to know the pid but otherwise it's http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid 
 More info from the man page

```
   WIFEXITED(status)
          returns true if the child terminated normally, that is, by
          calling exit(3) or _exit(2), or by returning from main().

   WEXITSTATUS(status)
          returns the exit status of the child.  This consists of the
          least significant 8 bits of the status argument that the child
          specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument
          for a return statement in main().  This macro should be
          employed only if WIFEXITED returned true.
```

Here is an example from the

```
   #include <sys/wait.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       pid_t cpid, w;
       int status;

       cpid = fork();
       if (cpid == -1) {
           perror("fork");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (cpid == 0) {            /* Code executed by child */
           printf("Child PID is %ld\n", (long) getpid());
           if (argc == 1)
               pause();                    /* Wait for signals */
           _exit(atoi(argv[1]));

       } else {                    /* Code executed by parent */
           do {
               w = waitpid(cpid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
               if (w == -1) {
                   perror("waitpid");
                   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
               }

               if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                   printf("exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status)); //this line will return the exit status, whether it was 1 or 0
               } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
                   printf("killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
               } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
                   printf("stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
               } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
                   printf("continued\n");
               }
           } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
   }
```

Comment: How could this help getting the return status code of the last command executed by the shell ? The command's process doesn't exists anymore when the C program is run.

Comment: This won't work unless the shell doesn't wait for its children (and you don't have zombies, because your shell waits for its children).

Comment: Read question carefully.

Comment: @Sevki, even though you've edited this to demonstrate use of waitpid() more exhaustively, that doesn't change that `waitpid()` won't work for a program that already had its exit status removed from the process table (by the parent shell itself calling `wait()`) before your program was started.